# png images automatically named alphabetically

Tags: php, image

i have a string 100 characters long. i want to form an `.png` image for each character of the string.
Here is my code

```
$grid_ch = "PKNHVJAYCLGCOLJWKRIWNYKOTICRNXUXIZUMPEFPSHAAMHFBOIMLKVIDQKSOATLLTIICYESTIEIHAASDQPLTDWHLDXSVCQRHSBOJ";
$grid_ch_arr = str_split($grid_ch);
foreach($grid_ch_arr as $k=>$v){
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(20, 30);
    $fill = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
    $border = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);
    imagefilltoborder($image, 0, 0, $border, $fill);
    imagestring($image, 5, 2, 2, $v, $text_color);
    $image_path = "../images/" . $v . ".png";
    imagepng($image,$image_path);
    echo $v . ",";
}
```

My problem is that the images formed are from A.png till Z.png. Why are the images being named as he english alphabets and not characters from my string.
I tried echoing the characters at the end of the the script and they are working fine.

Please help.

Comment: i only see ASCII characters in $grid_ch

Comment: Yep, only ASCII in that string - and any time a character is repeated, it will overwrite any previous file for that character. What do you expect the end result to be?

Comment: my end result will be files numbered 1.png till 100.png with each containing the characters

Comment: your not trying to create images for a captcha are you?

Comment: nope..the requirement is diff..anyways i got the desired output thanks to @Micheal Berkowski . I added a $i as file name and incremented it each time the loop ran. Thanks all

Comment: file names should use $k not $v if you want numbered 0-100

Comment: He is not using $v to increment the filename's number

Comment: @wernersbacher his question says a-z but his comment 1-100 so who know what he wants

Comment: Well, now- I see what he did there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want files named 1.png, 2.png and so on, change this line:

```
$image_path = "../images/" . $v . ".png";
```

To this one:

```
$image_path = "../images/" . $k . ".png";
```

Or also change `$k` to `$k+1`, if you really want images named from 1 to 100, and not from 0 to 99.

```
$image_path = "../images/" . $k+1 . ".png";
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not possible that a PNG file like S.png exists more than one time.
You need an extra if clause and rename always existing files to S_2.png or something like this.

Also I don't know why you should need more than 1 image per letter.

Tell us what you want to do. We could help you much better this way.